# How to run .jar file that scrapes data and updates mongoDB once daily on Azure

Tags: java, azure

I am trying to figure out how to run a .jar file on azure once daily.  It scrapes data from a small handful of websites and then updates a mongodb with relevant data.

I have a separate node app running on azure that serves the data from the database to the client and visualizes the data.

Currently I have to run the .jar file locally each day to update everything.  My impression is I can either find a way to get Azure to run the .jar file each morning, or a way to get my node app to execute the .jar file each morning, but cannot find a clear answer.

I have tried creating a java app in Azure, but it wants to run it as a website, and as it doesn't actual serve up any files, I get a ":( Application Error" from azure, and seems unlikely this isn't the correct route.  I know all this comes from a basic lack of understanding on Azure, but am having trouble figuring out even at a high level what sort of way I should look into running this.

Answer (score 0):

Incase anyone looks at this, I ended up with this solution.  I just execute the .jar file using nodejs:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var child = exec('java -jar ./theJarFileToRun.jar',
    function (error, stdout, stderr){
        console.log('Output -> ' + stdout);
        if(error !== null){
            console.log("Error -> "+error);
        }
    });
module.exports = child;
```